# Append and add information from rows above

Tags: mysql

the title is not really helpful. Sorry. I better explain with code. I need a query in MySQL for the following problem:

**Build schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE AsIs 
( 
`PN` VARCHAR(10),
`Origin`VARCHAR(10),
`Sub`VARCHAR(10) 
);

INSERT INTO AsIs 
VALUES ('11111', 'List1', '22222'), ('98765', 'List2', '123456');
```

I create a table with the column subs:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Subs` SELECT  `sub` AS `PN` FROM AsIs;
```

I create a table to union the values from table AsIs and table  `subs` :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `UnionAsISwithSubs`
SELECT `PN` FROM AsIs UNION SELECT `PN` FROM `subs`;
```

And finally I create the last table to add the information from the AsIs table:

```
`CREATE TABLE `FinalList`
SELECT `UnionAsISwithSubs`.`PN`,`AsIs`.`Origin`,`AsIs`.`sub` 
FROM `UnionAsISwithSubs`
LEFT JOIN AsIs ON `UnionAsISwithSubs`.`PN` = `AsIs`.`PN;
```

There are for sure better ways to do this, but my main question is, how can i update the column 'Origin` with the values from the row above. So it should like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ShouldBe Like AsIs;
INSERT INTO ShouldBe 
VALUES('11111', 'List1', '22222'),('98765', 'List2', '123456'),
('22222', 'List1', ''),('123456', 'List2', '');
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

I have simulate it with SQL fiddle. Please follow the link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd792/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your `AsIs` table into a row set like the `ShouldBe` table without any temporary tables, using a single query like this:

```
SELECT
  PN,
  Origin,
  Sub
FROM
  AsIs

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Sub,
  Origin,
  ''
FROM
  AsIs
;
```

The first half of the query just lists the current contents of the `AsIs` table. The second half appends the same rows but this time putting the `Sub` column at the same position as `PN` in the first query and specifying an empty string in place of the original `Sub`.

The column names of the final resulting set are defined by the names that the first SELECT is returning. So, `Sub` values of the second SELECT will be returned as `PN` in the output and the empty strings as `Sub` – that is, for your example the output will look like this:

```
PN      Origin  Sub
------  -----   ------
11111   List1   22222
98765   List2   123456
22222   List1
123456  List2
```